# NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException when trying to retrieve rows with Castle Active Record

Tags: activerecord, castle

I have a simple database in MsSQL2012 with two tables which I've created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
 Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
 Name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (Id) 
)    

CREATE TABLE Department
(
 Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
 Name varchar(255),
 Company_Id int NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (Company_Id) REFERENCES Company(Id)
);
```

Corresponding Castle active record classes:

**Company**

```
[ActiveRecord]
    public class Company : ActiveRecordBase<Company>
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Property]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [HasMany(typeof(Department))]
        public IList<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    }
```

**Department**

```
[ActiveRecord]
    public class Department : ActiveRecordBase<Department>
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Property]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [HasMany(typeof(Employee))]
        public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo(Type = typeof(Company), Column = "Id")]
        public Company Company
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

C# code to get companies and departments:

```
 ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(ActiveRecordSectionHandler.Instance, typeof(Company), typeof(Department));
 var companys = Company.FindAll();//ALL IS FINE, I get a list of companies
 var departments = Department.FindAll();//HERE IS EXCEPTION
```

**Exception**:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.ActiveRecordException: Could not perform
>   FindAll for Department ---> NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row
>   with the given identifier e xists[ActiveRecordDemo.Domain.Company#4]
>   at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.DefaultEntityNotFoundDelegate.HandleEntityNotFound(String
>   entityName, Object id)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent
>   event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType
>   options)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.ProxyOrLoad(LoadEvent
>   event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType
>   options)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent
>   event, LoadType loadType)    at
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType
>   loadType)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.InternalLoad(String
>   entityName, Object id, Boolean eager, Boolean isNullable)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object id,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.ResolveIdentifier(Object value,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)    at
>   NHibernate.Engine.TwoPhaseLoad.InitializeEntity(Object entity, Boolean
>   readOnly, ISessionImplementor session, PreLoadEvent preLoadEvent,
>   PostLoadEvent postLoadEvent)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.InitializeEntitiesAndCollections(IList
>   hydratedObjects, Object resultSetId, ISessionImplementor session,
>   Boolean readOnly)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoList(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListIgnoreQueryCache(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.List(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[]
>   resultTypes)    at
>   NHibernate.Loader.Criteria.CriteriaLoader.List(ISessionImplementor
>   session)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(CriteriaImpl criteria,
>   IList results)    at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List(IList results) 
>   at NHibernate.Impl.CriteriaImpl.List()    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType,
>   DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria, Order[] orders)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType,
>   DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria, Order[] orders)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.FindAll(Type targetType)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase`1.FindAll()

When I get companies all is OK, but with retrieving departments I get the above exception. Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get rid of this exception by adding *NotFoundBehaviour*.Ignore parameter to **BelongsToAttribute**:

```
[BelongsTo(Type = typeof(Company), Column = "Id", NotFoundBehaviour = NotFoundBehaviour.Ignore)]
```

and

```
[BelongsTo(Type = typeof(Department), Column = "Id", NotFoundBehaviour = NotFoundBehaviour.Ignore)]
```

Not sure if it is a solution or workaround ) but all is working fine and all unit tests passed.